# Replacing a substring AFTER a character in a python pandas dataframe

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and am having a lot of trouble with this and haven't found a solution, despite my searches. Hoping one of you can help me.

I have a pandas dataframe that has a column of emails that I'm trying to clean up. Some examples are:

```
>>> email['EMAIL']
0              testing@...com
1                         NaN
2           I.am.ME@GAMIL.COM
3    FIRST.LAST.NAME@MAIL.CMO
4    EMAIL+REMOVE@TESTING.COM
Name: EMAIL, dtype: object
```

There are a number of things I'm trying to do here:

1) replace misspelled endings (e.g. CMO) with correct spellings (e.g. COM)

2) replace misspelled domain names with correct spellings

3) replace multiple periods with just 1 period AFTER the '@' symbol.

4) remove all periods before the '@' sign if they have a gmail account

5) remove all characters after the "+" symbol up to the '@' symbol

So, from the example above I would have returned:

```
>>> email['EMAIL']
0                testing@.com
1                         NaN
2             IamME@GMAIL.COM
3    FIRST.LAST.NAME@MAIL.COM
4           EMAIL@TESTING.COM
Name: EMAIL, dtype: object
```

I've worked on a number of different codes and keep running into errors. Here's one of my best guesses so far, for removing multiple periods after the '@' symbol.

```
def remove_periods(email):
    email_split = email['EMAIL'].str.split('@')
    ending = email_split.str.get(-1)
    ending = ending.str.replace('\.{2,}', '.') 
    emailupdate = email_split.str[:-1]
    emailupdate.append(ending)
    email_split.str.get()
    return '@'.join(emailupdate)
email['EMAIL'].apply(remove_periods)
```

I could print the multiple other versions too, but they all returns errors too.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.width = 1000
email = pd.DataFrame({'EMAIL':[
    'testing@...com', np.nan, 'I.am.ME@GAMIL.COM', 'FIRST.LAST.NAME@MAIL.CMO', 
    'EMAIL+REMOVE@TESTING.COM', 'gamil@bar...com', 'noperiods@localhost']})

email[['NAME', '@', 'ADDR']] = email['EMAIL'].str.rpartition('@')

# 1) replace misspelled endings (e.g. COM) with correct spellings 
email['ADDR'] = email['ADDR'].str.replace(r'(?i)CMO$', 'COM')
# 2) replace misspelled domain names with correct spellings 
email['ADDR'] = email['ADDR'].str.replace(r'(?i)GAMIL', 'GMAIL')
# 3) replace multiple periods with just 1 period AFTER the '@' symbol. 
email['ADDR'] = email['ADDR'].str.replace(r'[.]{2,}', '.')
# 4) remove all periods before the '@' sign if they have a gmail account 
mask = email['ADDR'].str.contains(r'(?i)^GMAIL[.]COM$') == True
email.loc[mask, 'NAME'] = email.loc[mask, 'NAME'].str.replace(r'[.]', '')
# 5) remove all characters after the "+" symbol up to the '@' symbol
email['NAME'] = email['NAME'].str.replace(r'[+].*', '')

# put it back together. You could reassign to email['EMAIL'] if you wish.
email['NEW_EMAIL'] = email['NAME'] + email['@'] + email['ADDR']

# clean up intermediate columns
# del email[['NAME', '@', 'ADDR']]
print(email)
```

yields

```
                      EMAIL             NAME     @         ADDR                 NEW_EMAIL
0            testing@...com          testing     @         .com              testing@.com
1                       NaN              NaN  None         None                       NaN
2         I.am.ME@GAMIL.COM            IamME     @    GMAIL.COM           IamME@GMAIL.COM
3  FIRST.LAST.NAME@MAIL.CMO  FIRST.LAST.NAME     @     MAIL.COM  FIRST.LAST.NAME@MAIL.COM
4  EMAIL+REMOVE@TESTING.COM            EMAIL     @  TESTING.COM         EMAIL@TESTING.COM
5           gamil@bar...com            gamil     @      bar.com             gamil@bar.com
6       noperiods@localhost        noperiods     @    localhost       noperiods@localhost
```

The NAME column holds everything before the last `@`
The ADDR column holds everything after the last `@`.

I left the NAME, ADDR columns visible (and did not overwrite the original `EMAIL` column) 
so it would be easier to understand the intermediate steps.

Comment: wow! Thank you! I'm pretty amazed that you did it so elegantly. I was still putting together so much tedious code trying to do the same thing!